# Only get `character(0)` from ROracle conection

Tags: r, oracle, dbconnection, roracle

Does someone know why I am unable to get data tables from my ROracle connection configured as below?

```
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(drv,username =  "myusername", password =   "mypassword ")
```

Up to there it seems to be okay, I get the following items on my environment

**seeROracle environment**

[image: seeROracle environment]

But then, when I use `dbListTables(con)` to see which tables I recover, I just got `character(0)` like there is nothing in my Oracle database.

How can I view the tables?